# Wordpress global $post is changed from object to array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building some custom wordpress plugin and i want to get recent posts and get some data i need from it and return array. I done this but my problem is that after i added this code global variable $post is not anymore object, it is array now. Because that in my debug.log i have lots of warnings "Trying to get property of non-object" in different class where property of object is tried to get. For example ($post-ID)

```
    $recentPosts = wp_get_recent_posts($blogPostArguments, OBJECT);

    $posts = array();
    foreach($recentPosts as $recentPost){
        $avatar = get_avatar_url( $recentPost->post_author, 'default');
        $featuredImage = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recentPost->ID);
        $url = get_post_permalink($recentPost->ID);
        $categories = get_the_category($recentPost->ID);

        foreach($categories as $category){
            $category->url = get_category_link($category->term_id);
        }

        $authorFirstName = get_user_meta($recentPost->post_author, 'first_name', true);
        $authorLastName = get_user_meta($recentPost->post_author, 'last_name', true);
        $authorName = $authorFirstName . " " . $authorLastName;

        $post = array();
        $post['title'] = $recentPost->post_title;
        $post['content'] = $this->limitText($recentPost->post_content, 5);
        $post['featured_image'] = $featuredImage;
        $post['full_name'] = $authorName;
        $post['avatar'] = $avatar;
        $post['url'] = $url;
        $post['categories'] = $categories;
        array_push($posts, $post);
```

}

Comment: Probably you override the global $post. Use another variable: `$my_post = array();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rewrite the `$post = array();` did you try to change the variable name ? 
like `$tempPost = array();`.

Any how you should prefix all your variables in your plugin to avoid any present or future data collisions. (Usually a two or three letters acronyme).

Comment: Yes i rewrite it by mistake, did not see that i add global $post variable on beginning of method

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to foreach the $post before you use it.